# Release APK crash on start - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I have an issue with react native release APK.

The app run on debug mode but it crash immediately on release mode

Got these message from the logcat which is probably causing this problem

```
Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag) 
11-01 08:28:24.531  6644  6662 E ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.View.propTypes.style')
11-01 08:28:24.534  6644  6662 E ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Here is my packages :

```
  {
  "name": "jbw",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "color": "^2.0.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "native-base": "^2.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.3",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.6.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.9.38",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: where did You find the logfile?

Comment: you can use adb logcat for Android

Comment: didnt knew about that thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Got the problem, caused by

```
View.PropTypes
```

deprecated on 0.49 
should move to

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: no problem, seems like more problem related with this update will come up

Comment: on which file we have to add it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following steps:

1. `cd android`
2. `sudo ./gradlew clean`

If not works, you can check your `index.android.js` on the line:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAppName', () => MyRootComponent);
```

Verify if the name in (MyAppName) is the same of the name that are in `MainActivity.java` in the method `getMainComponentName()`

Comment: hello thanks for the suggestion, i already tried those, all the files already correct in my project, it runs well on debug build, the problem only appears on release build, any thoughts what happens?

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that you have:

```
"react-native": "0.50.3",
"react": "^16.0.0"
```

then do:

```
watchman watch-del-all
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

and everything will work well

credit to: @mobdim  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16745#issuecomment-343443988

i should mention that i had to fix also the problem mentioned here by Ganesh Cauda